# Javascript: java like package and class conflict issue

Tags: javascript

So I try to do something like Java to solve **class name conflict problem**. What I try is:

```
function com_mycompany_my_package(){
    function Class1(){
        this.field1=0;
    }

    Class1.prototype.increase=function(){
        this.field1=1;
    }

    function Class2(){
        this.field1=0;
    }

    Class2.prototype.descrease=function(){
        this.field1=-1;
    }

}

var class1=new ?
```

How can I get new instance of Class1? Is my way good or bad? What is other way to solve class name conflict problem?

Comment: See this: http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Java programming so I'd remove that tag.

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a modular approach. You can do

```
var com_mycompany_my_package = (function() {

    // Declare private variables here
    function Class1(){
        this.field1=0;
    }
    Class1.prototype.increase=function(){
        this.field1=1;
    }

    // Export public methods:
    return {
        Class1: Class1
    };

})();

var class1 = new com_mycompany_my_package.Class1();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. As I understand this case we create full instance of com_mycompany_my_package. And if this package has Class2,Class3,ClassN will we have perfomance problems?

Comment: @PashaTurok I don't think this would perform significantly worse than other approaches.